# Angular 2 JSONP, injected script did not invoke callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I'm using Angular 2.RC4 and typescript

I have class with data:

```
    import {Injectable, Injector, ReflectiveInjector} from '@angular/core';
import {
    Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, HTTP_PROVIDERS, Jsonp, JSONP_PROVIDERS,
    URLSearchParams
} from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import '../helpers/rxjs-operators';
import { caaConfig } from "../config/cmsaa";

getData(url: string): Observable<any>{
        let params  = new URLSearchParams();
        params.set('callback', 'JSONP_CALLBACK');
        url = this.domain + url;
        let cacheKey = 'cache_caa_http_get_' + url;
        if(this._cache[cacheKey]){
            return this._cache[cacheKey];
        }else{
            let request = this.jsonp.get(url, {search:params}).map(this.extractData).catch(this.handleError);
            this._cache[cacheKey] = request;
            return request;
            }
    }
```

In all sources: github issues, stackoverflow posts I saw that add callback parameter solve problem. In my case not.

My error is:

JSONP injected script did not invoke callback.

and url

[http://example.com/project/invoices/4137?callback=**ng_jsonp**.__req0.finished](http://example.com/project/invoices/4137?callback=__ng_jsonp__.__req0.finished)

In my bootstrap in included JSON_PROVIDERS.

Someone have idea what I should fix to get data from my remote server?

Comment: And what is the response you get to the HTTP request? (I assume that you aren't actually running your service on `domain.com` (please use `example.com` for example domains, that is what it is there for, `domain.com` is a real website.))

Comment: When I call in browser answer is JSON. By angular response is:

```
_body: JSONP injected script did not invoke callback.
status: 200
ok: true, 
type: 3
url: http://example.com/project/invoices/4137?callback=__ng_jsonp__.__req0.finished
```
this is error received because I have as error handler return `Observable.throw(error); `

I see this error in console, because in "network" tab in browser this request doesn't exists

Comment: That's the problem then. You are getting JSON instead of JSONP. If you are using JSONP then you have to get JSONP from the server as well as handling JSONP on the client.

Comment: to get JSON should I use JSON_CALLBACK instead JSONP_CALLBACK?
I've been tried but still I have same error.

I have not editable API on remote server which return JSON

Comment: If the remote server is returning JSON then you can't use JSONP. There is no `JSON_CALLBACK` option, the callback in the URL is a feature specific to JSONP.

Comment: Ok I understand. But what should I do? Because API is on remote server and http doesn't works on this. JSONP wants JSONP as response. When I use http I see as result

```
_body: error, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", url: null 
```
and in console error:
Request has been blocked „Same Origin Policy” not allow remote content from „http://example.com/project/invoices/4137”. (Needed headers CORS „Access-Control-Allow-Origin”)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35553666/19068

Comment: I "solved" problem by spoke to API owner. Now I can use http because he add this headers to response. Thanks Quentin

Answer (score 0):

Your code assumes that your server application uses the `callback` parameter in the returned payload. Your server could use another parameter like `c`.

The content of this parameter is used to generated a response payload  like below:

```
__ng_jsonp__.__req0.finished({ ... })
```

Otherwise, the callback won't be called within Angular 2 (what you have in your case).